# Not getting all the post data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My model function is not getting the post data information and there for when I click on the submit button through error. Where it should still process, keeps on saying incorrect database name when there is one all ready.

All the input arrays are working OK just need to be able to get that information on same controller.

```
$data['db_hostname'] = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
$data['db_username'] = $this->input->post('db_username');
$data['db_password'] = $this->input->post('db_password');
$data['db_database'] = $this->input->post('db_database');
$data['db_driver'] = $this->input->post('db_driver');
$data['db_prefix'] = $this->input->post('db_prefix');

$this->load->model('model_install');

$this->model_install->database($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
```

Tried

```
$this->model_install->database($this->input->post());
```

Tried

```
$this->model_install->database($this->input->get());
```

Tried

```
$this->model_install->database($this->input->get_post());
```

**On My Model**

```
public function database() {
        $data['db_prefix'] = $this->input->post('db_prefix');

        $file = FCPATH . '/codeigniter.sql';

        if (!file_exists($file)) { 
            exit('Could not load sql file: ' . $file); 
        }

        $lines = file($file);

        if ($lines) {
            $sql = '';

            foreach($lines as $line) {
                if ($line && (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--') && (substr($line, 0, 1) != '#')) {
                    $sql .= $line;

                    if (preg_match('/;\s*$/', $line)) {
                        $sql = str_replace("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `", "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" . $data['db_prefix'], $sql);
                        $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE `", "CREATE TABLE `" . $data['db_prefix'], $sql);
                        $sql = str_replace("INSERT INTO `", "INSERT INTO `" . $data['db_prefix'], $sql);

                        $this->db->query($sql);

                        $sql = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From where you are posting?

Answer (score 0):

First get all post datas in an array and then send that array to the model function.

To get post data

```
$xxxx=$this->input->post('yyyy');
```

Storing post data in array

```
 $data=array(
    'field_name_in_table'=>$xxxx
);
```

Sending to the model

```
  $this->model_install->database($data);
```

Model function is

```
 public function database($dat) {
    if ($this->db->insert('table_name', $dat)) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I load sql so when  database database has connection it should load all information in but as said in post has bug in controller area

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. Your problem is fetching data from database or inserting data to database ?

Comment: To get it in model you should send the $data['db_prefix'] as an argument in model function like $this->model_install->database($data['db_prefix'])

Comment: Error on that Message: Illegal string offset 'db_prefix' and still saying No database selected

Comment: Have you added databse details in application/config/database.php

Comment: the users information gets posted to the database.php when click on submit seems to load at same time.